# Enable / disable wifi via bash scripting on Android

Tags: android, bash, scripting, wifi

I am trying to enable / disable the wifi device in my android device in a bash script. I am using the terminal emulator and the program Script Manager to execute bash scripts on the phone (which is a rooted Nexus One).
The normal way to do this in linux would be something like

```
ifconfig eth0 up
```

That gives me

```
"eth0: no such device"
```

Trying 
    `iwconfig eth0`
gives the same, and

```
iwconfig
```

gives a list of devices with no eth0 on it. Now if I turn on wifi (manually from the GUI) and type

```
iwconfig
```

it shows eth0 with a lot of info.

My question is: How can I use the command line to turn on / off wifi? And why is eth0 disappearing from the device list when wifi is disabled?

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried wlan0? That's the traditional wireless interface. I know that the answer below worked for you, so that's great, but knowing's half the battle.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While it doesn't work in my non-rooted phone for obvious reasons, the results I'm obtaining are completely different while wifi is connected:

```
$ ifconfig eth0
eth0: ip 192.168.0.102 mask 255.255.255.0 flags [up broadcast running multicast]
$ ifconfig eth0 up
error: SIOCSIFFLAGS (Permission denied)
```

If you just want to turn wifi on or off you should use:

```
# svc wifi enable
```

or

```
# svc wifi disable
```

to see the help message

```
# svc wifi
Control the Wi-Fi manager

usage: svc wifi [enable|disable]
         Turn Wi-Fi on or off.

       svc wifi prefer
          Set Wi-Fi as the preferred data network
```

Comment: Hmm... WIth wifi ON, I get:

`$ ifconfig eth0`


`eth0: Cannot assign requested address`


`$ ifconfig eth0 up (or down)`


`error: SIOCSIFFLAGS (Permission denied)`

Comment: `# svc wifi enable`

That worked, thank you. Strange that I did not find that with Google.