# turn wifi through adb for android 4.0 version on XYBOARDS

Tags: android, shell, adb, android-wifi

How to turn on WIFI through adb on a motorola XYboard using android version 4.0

I have already tried the commands

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings 
adb shell input keyevent 20 & adb shell input keyevent 23
```

but it just takes to the wifi settings, but the keyevent 20 is not taking to the "ON/OFF" button. In the new 4.0 version of android, we have to do a click on ON/OFF btton next to the WIFI to turn it on. How do I get to click that button using adb

Is there a command that will turn the wifi ON directly like the one for bluetooth, I can use

```
adb shell am start -a android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE
```

for turning bluetooth ON.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461769/enable-disable-wifi-via-bash-scripting-on-android

Comment: does this command work only if the unit is rooted?. I tried it and the reply was  "svc wifi enable killed" and it didnot turn the wifi on!!..

Answer (score 0):

Please check the keyevent codes for your phone, the keyevents 20 and 23 are for Droid X, 
the other droid X keyEvents are listed in this post : [ADB Shell Input Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events)

So on your device the keycode events might be slightly different...